# Bring your own function not available

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I was hoping to link my Azure static web app to a function using the [Bring your own function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/static-web-apps/functions-bring-your-own) feature. However, I don't see the option for my web app:

[image]

I have set the `api_location` to a blank string when deploying the app via GitHub Actions:

```
  - name: Build And Deploy
    id: builddeploy
    uses: Azure/static-web-apps-deploy@v1
    with:
      azure_static_web_apps_api_token: ${{ secrets.AZURE_STATIC_WEB_APPS_API_TOKEN }}
      repo_token: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
      action: 'upload'
      app_location: '/'
      api_location: ''
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using the free plan, and Bring your own functions requires the standard plan. Once I change the hosting plan, the option became available.

Comment: Could you please [Accept it as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work), so that others who encounter the same issue can find this solution and fix their problem.